# twitter crawling hashtag with api for using python

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, hashtag

i want to crawling 10000 tweet in twitter, contain particular word with hashtag.

for example, contain hashtag, #love like this.

and crawl all hashtag in tweet.

for example, one tweet exist like this.

[i am sleepy #boring #tired #sleep]

and i want to crawl data, and see result like this.

"#boring" "#tired" "#sleep"

i expect to understand what i am saying.

i tried to crawl hashtag using twitter API for python.

but there are some error

my code following this:

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream

#Variables that contains the user credentials to access Twitter API 
access_token = "mytoken"
access_token_secret = "mytokenscret"
consumer_key = "consumerkey"
consumer_secret = "consumersecret"

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print data
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status


if __name__ == '__main__':

    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    stream = Stream(auth, l)
    stream.filter(track=['#happy'])
```

when i run this code, there are popup like this.
[image]

how to i fix this, and crawl tweet's all hashtag that tweet contain particular hashtag.

i tried python 3.3.4 and windows 8.1 64x.

please help me.

thanks for read my question.

Comment: Did you even look at the error message? You are literally missing parentheses in call to 'print'

Comment: @Keatinge i confuse that using print function python 2.x and 3.x my mistake thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems you are using Python 3.0+ and so you can't use `print "Hello world"`, you need to use `print("Hello world")` so just change your print calls to have parentheses.

Comment: Anytime! Happy coding =]